# Call links list programatically for Pelican site

Tags: python, pelican

I have a [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/) blog. I want to call the external links list programmatically, rather than hard code them into the template. For example, the blog post categories are called programmatically, e.g.,

```
{% for category, articles in categories[0:10] %}
<li><a href="/{{ category.url }}">{{ category }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}            
</div>
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">

{% for category, articles in categories[11:20] %}
<li><a href="/{{ category.url }}">{{ category }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
{% for category, articles in categories[21:30] %}
<li><a href="/{{ category.url }}">{{ category }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

So to be clear, I am looking to change this code to call from a single file which lists some external weblinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign them to the `LINKS` variable in your `pelicanconf.py` e.g.

```
LINKS = (
   ('my link 1', 'http://some.link.here'),
   ('my link 2', 'http://some.other.link.here')
)
```

and then call them in your template with

```
{% for name, link in LINKS %}
    <a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

All variable defined in your `pelicanconf.py`, as long as they are in all-caps, can be accessed in your templates.

See: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/themes.html#templates-and-variables

Comment: That's neat. Thanks. Does it generalise if I want another list, like noteworthy posts?

Comment: All variables defined in your settings file, as long as they are in all-caps, can be accessed from templates. See: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/themes.html#templates-and-variables

Comment: I did check the documentation but to no avail. Thanks for the clear and concise solution.

Comment: Here is an example. I used this idea to make my own custom template here: https://github.com/drart/mmenu-pelican . I have a variable called WORK_LINKS in base.html and I define this in my pelicanconf.py file in my content https://github.com/drart/adamtindale.com